# Sabre: "UNABLE TO VERIFY MCT" error in PassengerDetailsRQ

Tags: sabre

Sometimes I noticed I get this error in `PassengerDetailsRQ`.

> UNABLE TO VERIFY MCT FOR SEG 01 AT MAA

I tried calling  `EndTransaction` without passing `UpdatedBy Element`, then when I again call `PassengerDetailsRQ`, I got the same error.

What could have gone wrong, or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sabre documentation about the error can be found here:

https://formatfinder.sabre.com/Content/AirTravel/ErrorResponsesAirTravel/UNABLETOVERIFYMCTFORSEGXXATXXX.aspx?ItemID=dc63313a21cf43bfa951e0d6deeba124&tabtype=troubleshoot&documentId=dc63313a21cf43bfa951e0d6deeba124_troubleshoot

(Login parameters --> Agent Sign In: your SOAP API Username / Password: your Sabre API Password / PCC: your Sabre API 'Organization')